# Habilitar checkbox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tengo un modal donde poseo varios checkbox, pero hay uno en particular que al momento de cargar esta deshabilitado, pero al momento de activarlo no mantiene el Style correspondiente al Bootstrap. Si no que queda en gris (pero sí se puede hacer check).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es el check de abajo (Descanso por Maternidad) que se activa pero queda en ese color.

JavaScript:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById("DescansoMaternidad").disabled = true;
});

$("#sexoPersona").change(function() {
    let generoPersona = $("#sexoPersona").val();
    if(generoPersona == 1) {
        document.getElementById("DescansoMaternidad").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("DescansoMaternidad").disabled = true;
        $("#DescansoMaternidad").iCheck('uncheck');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="contTiempoCompe" class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="i-checks">
            <label id="lblDescansoMaternidad">
            <input type="checkbox" id="DescansoMaternidad" name="DescansoMaternidad" value="1" >
            <i></i>&nbsp;<strong>Descanso por Maternidad</strong>
            </label>                        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="i-checks">
            <label id="lblAutorizacionAusentarse">
            <input type="checkbox" id="AutorizacionAusentarse" name="AutorizacionAusentarse" value="1">
            <i></i>&nbsp;<strong>Autorizaci&oacute;n Programada para Ausentarse</strong>
            </label>                        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probablemente tiene la clase 'disabled' del plugin que utilizas.

Comment: como así? @LuiscYm

Comment: Si, puede que en el html que pinta ese elemento tenga la clase o la propiedad disabled. Por lo cual el check tiene ese aspecto. Sería bueno que agregues el html para descartar esa posibilidad.

Comment: Listo @LuiscYm documento modiicado

Comment: Parece todo bien, revisa la documentación http://icheck.fronteed.com/ quiza te pueda servir.

Comment: Indicanos por favor qué libreria CSS estás usando o añade el respectivo a los checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias utilizar las propiedades de Jquery nativas para checkear y deshabilitar.

```
$('#DescansoMaternidad').prop('checked', true);
$('#DescansoMaternidad').prop('checked', false);
```

y

```
$("#DescansoMaternidad").attr("disabled", true);
$("#DescansoMaternidad").attr("disabled", false);
```

Intenta utilizar el siguiente código y me comentas:

```
$("#sexoPersona").change(function(){
    let generoPersona = $("#sexoPersona").val();
    if(generoPersona == 1){
        $("#DescansoMaternidad").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#DescansoMaternidad").removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#DescansoMaternidad').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled');
    }else{
        $("#DescansoMaternidad").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#DescansoMaternidad").prop("checked", false);

        $('#DescansoMaternidad').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');

    }
```

Comment: Sigue igual... se puede checkear pero queda en gris

Comment: Estimado, añadí 2 líneas de código que quitan o agregan la propiedad señalada, me comentas como te va.

Comment: Queda igual, no exste un cambio visible :/

Comment: mmm, mira, voy a editar nuevamente la respuesta. **EDIT** en la edición añadí removeClass y addClass para setear correctamente los cambios de CSS. Me comentas

Comment: nada de nada, refresque y limpie caché

Comment: Que CSS estás ocupando? alguna librería en especial? o una skin con un bootstrap integrado?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.

Te comento que tomé el extracto de tu código, lo pegué en uno de mis proyectos y el checkbox no funcionaba ya que no me dejaba hacer el check, asi que cambié el true por false de tu javascript y funciona tanto el check como el estilo.

Te dejo la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva...